# java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked (database is locked)

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I keep getting the SQLITE_BUSY database file is locked error. I have looked on other posts, but none have solved this issue. Can't seem to figure out why this error is occurring. I know that you are only supposed to have one connection at a time, but it appears that I do only have one connection. Any ideas? Does it have something to do with the fact that object `Connection connection` is initialized as null then reset? Thats the only thing I could think of, however if I take it away, then I am not able to close the connection in the finally block.

```
public class GetChromeHistory
{
public static void main (String[] args) 
{

Connection connection= null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
Statement statement = null;

try 
    {

    // We think, but are not sure, that the line below registers the sqlite drive with JDBC.
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      connection = DriverManager
        .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db.db");
    statement = connection.createStatement();

    //problem occurs on line below, database file is locked
    resultSet = statement
        .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM urls where visit_count > 0");


    while(resultSet.next()) 
        {

        //eventually save into a set or list 
        System.out.println ("URL [" + resultSet.getString("url") + "]" +
                    ", visit count [" + resultSet.getString("visit_count") + "]");
        }
    }   

catch(Exception e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 

finally 
    {
    try 
        {
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
        } 

    catch(Exception e) 
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Such a thing happened once when I held a DB open in the IDE and at the same time tried to run the application.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Are you suggesting that it is because I am trying to use the DB in an Eclipse Runtime Application instead of Workspace?

Comment: Same is the case with me as @JoopEggen

Comment: Also if it is needed to execute n no of times, and got struck in the middle of execution, later statements will give u that exception

Comment: Thanks @JoopEggen, I believe that it my problem. I appreciate it!